# Jlink cannot find module java.activation with Ehcache 3.10.8

Tags: gradle, java-module, jlink, ehcache-3

I'm trying to package an application using Ehcache and when I run `./gradlew jlink` I get an error. The `createMergedModule` task fails with `module not found: java.activation`

Here is my minimal build.gradle (tried with 7.6.1, 8.5, 8.6, same results) :

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.beryx.jlink" version "3.0.1"
    id "org.gradlex.extra-java-module-info" version "1.8"
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ehcache/ehcache
    implementation group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.10.8'
    implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'javax.activation-api', version: '1.2.0'

    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    addExtraDependencies("javax.activation")
}

extraJavaModuleInfo {
    automaticModule("ehcache-3.10.8.jar", "ehcache")
    automaticModule("cache-api-1.1.0.jar", "cache.api")
    automaticModule("javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar", "java.activation") {
        mergeJar("javax.activation:javax.activation-api")
    }
}
```

And my `module-info.java`

```
module cache.main {
    requires ehcache;
    // requires java.activation; // <-- compile error if automaticModule() is used.
}
```

I've tried adding `forceMerge()` and `addExtraDependencies()` options in jlink{}; adding several different dependencies; using `org.javamodularity.moduleplugin` instead of `org.gradlex.extra-java-module-info` and I still get the same error.

The MANIFEST.MF in `javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar` lists `Automatic-Module-Name: java.activation`.
Shouldn't jlink use that when creating the merged module?

I've written some code to test ehcache and the code builds and runs fine, but JLink and JPackage tasks fail.